# How change the value in lightning iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, aura-iteration

I want change the value in the iteration. I want show fields of Account: Item_1__c, Item_2__c, Item_3__c, Item_4__c..... (we have 12custom fields Item_X__c, but we want show only 6 by default, and show more if user click on button addColumns).
This numbers are in a table, and the user can fill it.

```
<ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{! 'account.Item_' + cont + '__c'}" change="{!c.calculateSum}"/>
```

In the code, we want access to account, and dynamic value (changing the field). But this is not work, and error appear:
Uncaught Action failed: ui:inputSmartNumber$controller$handleChangeEvent [Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Thanks

COMPONENT

```
<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="numCol" type="List" default="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" description="Number of columns."/>

<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToSObject" type="EVENT"/>

<ltng:require styles="/resource/slds_resource/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css?v=1" />
<div class="slds">
    <div class="slds-page-header noborderbottom" role="banner"> 
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                <div class="slds-media slds-no-space slds-grow">
                    <div class="slds-media__figure">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="custom:custom17" size="large" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                        <p class="slds-text-title_caps slds-line-height_reset">Account</p>
                        <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right_small slds-align-middle slds-truncate" title="My Accounts">My Accounts</h1>
                    </div>
                    <lightning:button class="slds-float_right" iconName="utility:add" onclick="{!c.addColumn}" label="Add column"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

<div class="slds" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal" aura:id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-heading--label" aura:id="tr_myTable">
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Account Name">
                    <div>Name</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Estimate">
                    <div>Estimate</div>
                </th>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.numCol}" var="cont">
                    <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Item">
                        <div>Item {!cont}</div>
                    </th>
                </aura:iteration>
                <th scope="col" class="nobordertop" title="Total">
                    <div>Total</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="account">
                <tr aura:id="tr_myTable">
                    <td data-label="Name" title="Name">
                        <div><a data-record="{!account.Id}" onclick="{!c.redirectToSobject}">{!account.Name}</a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Account Number" title="Horas estimadas">
                        <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!account.Estimate__c}" change="{!c.calculateSum}" disabled="true"/></div>
                    </td>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.numCol}" var="cont">
                        <td data-label="{! 'Item ' + cont}" title="{! 'Item ' + cont}">
                            <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{! 'account.Item_' + cont + '__c'}" change="{!c.calculateSum}"/></div>
                        </td>
                    </aura:iteration>
                    <td data-label="Account Number" title="Total">
                        <div><ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{!account.Sum__c}" change="{!c.calculateSum}"/></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

CONTROLLER & HELPER

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {       
    helper.getAccounts(component);
},

getAccounts: function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAllDesgloseCoste");
    action.setParams({opportunityId: component.get('v.recordId')});   
    //Set up the callback
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        component.set("v.accounts", actionResult.getReturnValue());
    }); 
    $A.enqueueAction(action);  
},

calculateSum: function(component, event){
        var allRows = component.get("v.accounts");
        for(var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++){
            var totalHours;
            if(allRows[i].Item_1__c){
                totalHours += allRows[i].Item_1__c;            
            }
            if(allRows[i].Item_2__c){
                totalHours += allRows[i].Item_2__c;            
            }
            if(allRows[i].Item_3__c){
                totalHours += allRows[i].Item_3__c;            
            }
            if(allRows[i].Item_4__c){
                totalHours += allRows[i].Item_4__c;            
            }
            if(allRows[i].Item_5__c){
                totalHours += allRows[i].Item_5__c;            
            }
            if(allRows[i].Item_6__c){
                totalHours += allRows[i].Item_6__c;            
            }

            if(totalHours){
                allRows[i].Sum__c = totalHours;
            }

        }
        component.set("v.accounts", allRows);
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Slds-hide or aura:if to display them conditionally.

```
<aura:attribute name="advMode" type="Boolean" default="false" />

<ui:inputNumber class="{!v.advMode ? 'slds-input' : 'slds-hide' }" value="{! 'account.Item_' + cont + '__c'}" change="{!c.calculateSum}"/>
```

For [Maximum call stack size exceeded] errors, avoid nested aura:iteration(s), That usually gives a starting point for debugging.

Also, In the sample code provided, i am not seeing the *c.calculateSum* implementation.